# javascript not adding html div to string

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm working with a wordpress plugin called Wordpress Simple Paypal Shopping Cart, when the form is sent it starts this script. It takes a product, and three dropdown and puts them into a format in one string like this:

> SHOP ITEM (dropdown1) (dropdown2) (dropdown3)

Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    //
    function ReadForm (obj1, tst)
    {
        // Read the user form
        var i,j,pos;
        val_total="";val_combo="";

        for (i=0; i<obj1.length; i++)
        {
            // run entire form
            obj = obj1.elements[i];           // a form element

            if (obj.type == "select-one")
            {   // just selects
                if (obj.name == "quantity" ||
                    obj.name == "amount") continue;
                pos = obj.selectedIndex;        // which option selected
                val = obj.options[pos].value;   // selected value
                val_combo = val_combo + " (" + val + ")";
            }
        }
        // Now summarize everything we have processed above
        val_total = obj1.product_tmp.value + val_combo;
        obj1.product.value = val_total;
    }
    //-->
    </script>';
```

I need to change the output so I can style the three options with specific CSS. The output in HTML is in a span.
I notice the line `val_combo = val_combo + " (" + val + ")";` adds the brackets around the output so I tried to change it to `val_combo = val_combo + " <div>" + val + "</div>";` but the output strips the divs, leaving the output like:

> SHOP ITEM dropdown1 dropdown2 dropdown3

I'm not clever with Javascript so any examples as if for a child would be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the snipped that you posted, you wrote **val_combo = val_combo + " <div class='example'>" + val + "<div>";** but this is broken since the closing div is *not* closing. Are you sure the code you tried was not broken as well? Also, give us a jsFiddle if possible.

Comment: val_combo = val_combo + " <div>" + val + "</div>";
The example was actually correct and without a class as the plugin adds it by echoing. I was going to change the div using .container .div in css.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention about jsFiddle, not sure I can with it being a wordpress plugin and working locally.

Comment: Please eleborate on where the output is going. It seems like 'obj1.product.value = val_total;' is putting the value in a input box or something. This is probably also what is going wrong.

Comment: I'm looking for this now, there is no reference to 'obj1.product.value' anywhere else in the plugin.

There is a $_SESSION['simpleCart'] which is an array, but I can't see where it's getting it's original data from the form.

Comment: Am I right in assuming then that what's written there should have worked? And that the problem must be elsewhere?